# Find a String in xml file and assign its value to another String

Tags: java

I have the below plist.

```
    <?xml version="1.5" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//PSect//ACD PLIST 1.5//" "http://pset.com/ACD/plist.dtd">
<plist version="1.5">
<dict>
        <key>City</key>
        <string>Melbourne</string>
        <key>DetailedInfo</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Name</key>
                <real>Sam</real>
                <key>Income</key>
                <real>4000</real>
        </dict>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>Single</string>
        <key>PIN</key>
        <string>123456789</string>
</dict>
```

I have the code to parse this plist into an xml file. What I need help with is to find the key City in the plist. I have looked at some posts to search for a string in an xml file, but haven't had much luck. Basically what I want to do is,

```
1. Check if my xml file has Key City
2. If it does, assign its value (Melbourne) to another String.
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this? Please suggest.

Comment: Please specify with which apis / libraries you are working or show the code you have until now. There is a ton of ways to do what you want. To get a fitting solution, you need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Maththias - I only have the code to parse the xml file using standard file I/O. I haven't been able to go beyond this in reading this specific string, and assigning its value to another string.

Comment: Can someone please suggest?

Comment: @rickygrimes Well if you do this all with manual file IO, then better show your code, so we can point out ways to fix the issues. However I strongly encourage you to have a look at either JAXB/XStream for data binding or XSLT for extraction / reformatting an XML document if this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure of the doctype you have in your plist but try this
try this

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String keyVal = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new File("input.xml"));
        NodeList keyList = document.getElementsByTagName("key");

        if(keyList !=null && keyList.getLength() > 0) {
            for(int i =0; i< keyList.getLength(); i++) {
                keyVal = keyList.item(i).getTextContent();
                if ("City".equals(keyVal)) {
                    NodeList stringList = document.getElementsByTagName("string");
                    if(stringList !=null && stringList.getLength() > 0) {
                        System.out.println(stringList.item(i).getTextContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about finding this in an xml? I have already read the file contents into a String by following steps listed here - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/ So if I have to check the string for my key, then how do I do it?

Comment: Appreciate your answer. +1 for your efforts, also it can be one of the  solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
    XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) path.evaluate("//dict[key/text()='City']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    if (nl.getLength() == 1) {
        Element dictElement = (Element) nl.item(0);

        NodeList stringNodeList = dictElement.getElementsByTagName("string");
        for (int i = 0; i < stringNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            // replace string here
            System.out.println("Replace: " + stringNodeList.item(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about finding this in an xml? I have already read the file contents into a String by following steps listed here - mkyong.com/java/… So if I have to check the string for my key, then how do I do it?

Comment: Read in Document like:         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new File("input.xml"));

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use object-xml binding framework like jaxb or xtream to do this. Those frameworks would create an object out of your xml and it will be very easy to navigate this xml then. for example you could do if("City".equals(getDict().getKey()) { then do this}